# Smallest algebra generated by $\mathcal{C}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $X$ be an arbitrary fixed set and let $\mathcal{C}$ be a nonempty class of subsets of $X$ that contains $X$. 
How would you prove the smallest algebra $\mathcal{C}$ consist exactly of finite intersections of finite unions of sets $A \in \mathcal{C}$ and sets $A$ such that $A^c \in \mathcal{C}$?

Comment: This is certainly false. Where did you get this from?

Comment: My prof assigned it as a practice-for-the-test problem. What would be the reasoning to show this is false?

Comment: $\sigma (\mathcal C)$ stands for the sigma algebra generated by $\mathcal C$. The sets you have described don't go beyond the algebra generated by $\mathcal C$. Are you sure you did now misquote the question?

Comment: You are right it is about the smallest algebra and not sigma-algebra. I edited the question.